# Unable to Compile Code in LXC BusyBox Container

Tags: c, gcc, cross-compiling, busybox, lxc

I'm facing issues compiling code within an LXC container based on BusyBox. I've tried installing GCC using both apk and apt-get, but it outputs the command not found. I've heard about cross-compilation but am unsure how to proceed. Can someone guide me on how to successfully compile code within an LXC BusyBox container or provide steps for cross-compilation?